# (Short-Time) Fourier Transform: some notational problem.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

The following definition of a short-time Fourier Transform (STFT) is well known in the literature: let $f,g \in L^2(\Bbb R^d)$ be two functions. The short-time Fourier Transform of $f$ w.r.t $g$ is given by

$$ V_gf(x,\xi) := (f \, T_x\bar g)\widehat{}(\xi) = \int_{\Bbb R^d } f(t)\overline{g(t-x)}e^{-2\pi i t \cdot \xi} \, dt, $$
for $x,\xi \in \Bbb R^d$.

My question is somewhat simpler, but derives from this definition. In fact, my question can be resumed to the usual Fourier Transform. More precisely, I am getting very confused about the expression below:

$$ (V_gf \, \overline{V_u h})\widehat{}(x,\xi). $$

In simple terms, this should be the usual Fourier Transform of the product between the two functions in parentheses. This is causing me trouble because I can't write out this expression in  terms of integrals explicitily. I believe my problem comes from the understanding of what exactly is a Fourier transform of a function in two variables.

I obviously know that given a function $f$, we define its Fourier Transform by

$$ \hat{f}(w) = \int_{\Bbb R^d} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \cdot w} dx, $$
for all $w \in \Bbb R^d$. I don't know how to extend this to the $2$-D case and I believe that's my only issue understand the problem presented above.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: First, make sure you understand what "$x \cdot w$" means. Then try to understand what $(x,\xi)\cdot (y,\omega)$ means.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for your comment. I understand that "$x \cdot w$" stands for the usual inner product in $\Bbb R^d$, i.e., $$ x \cdot w = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i w_i .$$ Note that here I took $ x = (x_1,\dots,x_d) $ and analogously for $w$. This gives me the intuition that $ (x,\xi) \cdot (y,\omega) $ must be defined by $ (x \cdot y, \xi \cdot \omega).$ Is my intuition correct? Is this expression involved in the Transform I am working with ?

Comment: No, your interpretation results in a 2-dimensional vector, but you need a number. It is $x \cdot y + \xi \cdot \omega$.

Comment: @PhoemueX This means that the Fourier Transform I am working with will have two exponential functions, correct ? In some sense, can I decompose it into two simpler Fourier transforms ?

Comment: You will get a product of 2 exponentials (each of which is a product of d exponentials), yes.